# Save data in mysql table with php for every date and then print it date wise

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i am trying to make a program by which i can show any specific keywords (search term), how many times got searched on specific date.
I am if someone is searching for Stackoverflow so i want to show its searching stats on for specific data.
For example;

```
at 2013-04-01 -> stackoverflow was searched for 15 times<br>
at 2013-04-02 -> stackoverflow was searched for 28 times<br>
at 2013-04-03 -> stackoverflow was searched for 10 times<br>
```

I hope now you will understand what i want to say.,.
Now let me show what i have done for making this program.

See this code

```
<?php
$keyword = null;

if (!empty($_GET['s'])) {


$keyword = stripslashes($_GET['s']);

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `search` (`keyword`)
            VALUES (:keyword)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `times` = `times` + 1";

    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array(':keyword' => $keyword));

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


  }


  try {

$objDb = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');




  $sql = "SELECT `s`.*,
        IF (
            (
                SELECT `id`
                FROM `search` 
                ORDER BY `date` DESC
                LIMIT 0, 1
            ) = `s`.`id`,
            1,
            0
        ) AS `latest`
        FROM `search` `s`
        ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0, 50";




$statement = $objDb->query($sql);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  } catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Save search requests to database</title>
<meta name="description" content="Save search requests to database" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Save search requests to database" />
<link href="/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

  <section id="wrapper">    

 <form method="get">
     <input type="text" name="s" id="search" class="field" value="<?php echo    $keyword; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if (!empty($result)) { ?>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tbl_repeat">
        <tr>
            <th>Keyword</th>
            <th class="tar">Searched</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
        <tr<?php echo $row['latest'] == 1 ? ' class="active"' : null; ?>>
            <td><?php echo $row['keyword']; ?></td>
            <td class="tar"><?php echo $row['times']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

 <?php } else { ?>
    <p>There are currently no searches available.</p>
 <?php } ?>

  </section>

  </body>
  </html>
```

This is a simple program which saves recently searched keywords in the database and show it on the webpage and it also shows that how many times a keyword get search.. actually it just replace the current timestamp with updated timestamp..
Now anyone can please help to add a specific condition by which it will check todays date and then it will add the entry in the database and if that particular word got researched at the same day then it will just update current_timestamp with updated time stamp.
I just want to divide recent search queries on basis of date.

And this is the code of making this table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `search` ( <br>
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, <br>
`keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL, <br>
`times` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '1', <br>
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, <br>
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`), <br> 
 UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`) <br>
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=301 ; <br>
```

Please reply with an example data..

Comment: So GROUP BY the date in your query, and COUNT the values for each group.

Comment: How to save search queries by GROUP in the database..plz explain it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT keywords, COUNT(*) as no_of_times, date 
FROM search 
GROUP BY date, keywords
```

which will give you something like

```
keywords      | no_of_times | date       |
------------------------------------------
stackoverflow |    25       | 2012-10-12 |
meta          |    10       | 2012-10-12 |
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f634a/2)

Comment: See, if stackoverflow was searched for 25 times on 2012-10-12 so it will show it but if stackoverflow will get searched on 2012-10-13 for 5 times then maybe your concept will show it for 35 times bcoz on ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `times` = `times` + 1"; but i want to show it if stackoverflow was searched 25 times on 2012-10-12 and after then it was searched 5 times on 2012-1013 so it must show somthing like this..stackoverflow => 25 times (2102-10-13) and stackoverflow => 5 times (2012-10-13)..so is it possible with your concept..

Comment: Check out the demo [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f634a/2)  All you have to do is remove the unique key on `keyword` column

Comment: Hmm..It seems like my requirement.. Thank you very much for your help... i am going to check this on pc xampp..Then i will reply you about it.

Comment: Hey i have tested it.. it is but there's a problem with this code. You have added search queries in the database manually but if i am tring to add it by making a search term then your commed...SELECT keyword, COUNT(*) as no_of_times, date 
FROM search 
GROUP BY date, keyword .......Does not work properly bcoz every search term has it is own time and date see this stackoverflwo - 2013-04-03 19:26:50 -> 1 times and stackoverflwo - 2013-04-03 19:26:52 -> 1 times...Now how to get rid of from this situation..i dont want to save its time in the database i just want to save its date..

Comment: Simply change the data type of the `date` column to date, i.e, change `date timestamp` to `date date`

Comment: If you are talking about this.. `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,....it is giving an error..#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'...

Comment: Thanks after doing some adjustments i got it workable as i want...Thank you very much for showing me a right way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution , that I can think of now.

```
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$select = mysqli_query("select * from search where keyword='$search_term' and date='$date'");
$rowCheck = mysqli_num_rows($select);
if($rowCheck>0) {
 $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
 $times = $fetch['times'];
 $update_query = // RUN UPDATE QUERY HERE
} else {
  // RUN INSERT QUERY HERE
}
```

Hope this helps